# SFDX plugin is not getting Updated

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I am running this command:- **sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release** 
and getting this error message:-

```
    Installing plugin salesforcedx@pre-release... 
    Installing plugin salesforcedx@pre-release... Checking for digital signature. 
    Finished digital signature check. Installing... !  !    
    'ETIMEDOUT': connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.16.35:443
```

Its telling about timed out but how we can overcome of this? Why this is occuring?

Comment: As Spring 19 is available now. So you might not need a pre-release version. Can you try normal update? Else switch the internet.

Comment: You mean normal update of sfdx cli? Also, Spring 19 is not yet available in Dev HUB. It comes only in Sandbox as of now.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If so, be sure you set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` correctly. You can also prefix your command with `DEBUG=* sfdx <...>` to get more insight into what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, @WadeWegner, yes I believe I am on the proxy. Can you tell me the steps to set that as an answer to this question?